# Lift session-valid ajax callback from a static javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, lift

I am currently implementing a graph visualisation tool using lift on the server side and d3 ( a javascript visualisation framework) for all the visualisation. The problem I have is that in the script I want to get session dependent data from the server.

So basically, my objective is to write lift-valid ajax callbacks in a static js script.

## What I have tried so far

If you feel that the best solution is one that I already tried feel free to post a detailed answer telling me how to use it exactly and how it completely solves my problem.

#### Write the ajax callback in another script using lift and call it from the main script

This solution, which is similar to a hidden text input is probably the more likely to work. However it is not elegant and it would mean that I would have to load a lot of scripts on load, which is not really conveniant.

This seems to be one of the prefered solutions in the lift community as explained in [this discussion on the mailing list.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/ZDSsDMj-KRk/discussion)

#### REST interface

Usually what one would do to get data from a javascript function in lift is to create a REST interface. However this interface will not be linked to any session. This is the solution I got from my previous question: [Get json data in d3 from lift snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800612/get-json-data-in-d3-from-lift-snippet)

#### Give function as argument of script

Another solution would be to give the ajaxcallback as an argument of the main script called to generate my graph. However I expect to have a lot of callbacks and I don't want to have to mess with the arguments of my script.

#### Write the whole script in lift and then serve it to the client

This solution can be elegant, however my script is very long and I would really prefer that it remainss static.

## What I want

#### On client side

While reviewing the source code of my webpage I found that the callback for an ajaxSelect is:

```
<select onchange="liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler('F966066257023LYKF4=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value), null, null, null)" name="F96606625703QXTSWU" id="node_delete" class="input">
```

Moreover, there is a variable containing the state of the page in the end of the webpage:

```
var lift_page = "F96606625700QRXLDO";
```

So, I am wondering if it is possible to simulate that my ajaxcall is valid using this `liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler` function. However I don't know the exact synthax to use.

#### On server side

Since I "forged" a request on client side, I would now like to get the request on client side and to dispatch it to the correct function. This is where the `LiftRules.dispatch` object seems the best solution: when it is called, all the session management has been made (the request is authentified and linked to a session), however I don't know how to write the correct piece of code in the `append` function.

#### Remark

In lift all names of variables are changed to a random string in order to increase the security, I would like to have the same behavior in my application even if that will probably mean that I will have to "give" the javascript these values. However an array of 15 string values is still a better tradeoff than 15 functions as argument of a javascript function.

#### Edit

While following my research I found this page : [Mapping server functions to client actions](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mapping_server_functions_to_client_actions) which somehow explains the goal of named functions even if it stil didn't lead me to a working solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Quick Answer

Rest in Lift does not have to be stateless.  If you register your RestHelper with LiftRules.dispatch.append, then it will be handled statefully and Session information will be available through the S object as usual.

### Long Answer

Since you seem interested, and it's come up on SO before, here's a more detailed explanation of how server-side functions are registered and called in Lift.  If you haven't worked with Lift for some time, look away.  What follows should not in any way be used to evaluate Lift or its complexity.  This is purely library developer level stuff and a majority of Lift users go about their development blissfully unaware of it.

#### How it works

When you create stateful callbacks, typically by using the methods within the SHtml object, what you are really doing is registering objects of type S.AFuncHolder within the context of the users session, each with a unique ID.  The unique ID that was generated during this process is what you're seeing when you come across a pattern like `F96606625700QRXLDO`.  When data is submitted, via form post, ajax, or whatever, Lift will check the request for these function ids and execute the associated function if they exist.  There are several helpers that provide more specific types of AFuncHolder, like S.SFuncHolder (accepts a single string query parameter) and S.BinFuncHolder (parameter is multipart form data) but they all return Any and behind the scenes Lift will collect those return values to create the proper type of response. A JsCmd, for instance, will result in a JavaScriptResponse that executes the command.  You can also return a LiftResponse directly.

#### How to use it

AFuncHolders are registered using the S.fmapFunc method.  You'd call it like this

```
S.fmapFunc(SFuncHolder({ (str: String) =>
  doSomethingAwesomeWithAString(str)
}))(id => <input type="text" name={id} value=""/>)
```

The first parameter is your function, wrapped in the proper *FuncHolder type and the second parameter is a function that takes the generated id and outputs *something*.  The *something* that gets output is what you will include on the page.  It should somehow result in the id being sent to the server as a query parameter so that your function is executed.

#### Putting it all together

You could use the above to make your own Ajax calls, but when Lift makes an ajax call there are a few other considerations:

1) Most browsers only allow so many simultaneous connections to a given domain.  Three seems to be the magic number.
2) AFuncHolders will often close over the scope of the snippet they are contained within and if multiple ajax requests are handled at once, each in its own thread, bad things can happen.

To combat these issues, the `liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler` function queues each ajax request, ensuring that only one at a time is sent to the server.

The drawback to this approach is that it can make it difficult to make an Ajax call where the result needs to be passed to a callback.  JQuery autocomplete, for instance, provides a callback function when input changes that accepts a list of matches.  If you are manually calling LiftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler though, you can provide your own callback functions for success & error and I would recommend that you look at the source of those functions in your browser for more information on how they work.

There's actually more to it, like how Lift restores RequestVars on ajax callbacks (which is where the lift_page comes in, but that's about all I'm prepared to explain over coffee on a Saturday morning :)

Good luck with your app!

Comment: That's a great answer thanks! I finally decided to keep it simple and to include the callback in another function as described in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/ZDSsDMj-KRk/discussion  . However your answer really helps me put together all I searched for hours and I am sure it will help others.